# users-add.php:217 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, dom

the problem exctly that i'm trying to get th data for editing my users list when i press to the botton a UPDATEUSER, the same as i made on deleteuser for deleting the users by it's id from my table,

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header('location: login.php');
$_SESSION['table'] = 'users';
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$users = include('database/show-users.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard - Assure ERP System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css?v=<? time(); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dashboardmaincontainer">
        <?php include('partials/app-sidebar.php')?>
<div class="dashboard_content_container" id="dashboard_content_container">
    <?php include('partials/app-topnav.php')?>
    <div id="dashboard_content">
    <div class="dashboard_content_main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-5">
        <h1 class="sectionheader"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Insert User</h1>
      <div id="useraddformcontainer">
      <form action="database/user-add.php" method="POST" class="appform">
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="first_name">first name</label>
          <input type="text" class="appforminput" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="last_name">last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="appforminput" id="last_name" name="last_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="appforminput" id="email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="appforminput" id="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="appbtn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>add user</button>
      </form>
       <?php if(isset($_SESSION['response'])) {
              $response_message = $_SESSION['response']['message'];
              $is_success = $_SESSION['response']['success'];
              ?>
              <div class="responsemessage">
                <p class="responsemessage <?= $is_success ? 'responsemessage__success' : 'responsemessage__error'?>">
                  <?= $response_message ?>
                </p>
              </div>
            <?php unset($_SESSION['response']); }?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-7">
        
        <h1 class="sectionheader"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> List of Users</h1>
        <div class="section_content">
          <div class="users">
         <table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>#</td>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Created At</th>
<th>Updated At</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($users as $index => $user){?>
    
    

    <tr>
    <td><?= $index + 1?></td>
  <td class="firstName"><?= $user['first_name']?></td>
  <td class="lastName"><?= $user['last_name']?></td>
  <td class="userName"><?= $user['username']?></td>
  <td><?= date('M d, Y @ h:i:s A', strtotime($user['created_at'])) ?></td>
  <td><?= date('M d, Y @ h:i:s A', strtotime($user['updated_at'])) ?></td>
  <td>
    <a href="" class="updateUser" data-userid="<?= $user['id'] ?>" > <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
      <a href="" class="deleteUser" data-userid="<?= $user['id'] ?>" data-fname="<?= $user['first_name'] ?>" data-lname="<?= $user['last_name'] ?>" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
        </td>
</tr>  
  <?php }?>

</tbody>
</table>
  <p class="usercount"><?= count($users)?> Users</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

and now the script that includes my problem "updateUser" :

```
    <script>    function script(){
  this.initialize = function(){
    this.registerEvents();
  };

  this.registerEvents = function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      targetElement = e.target;
      classList = targetElement.classList;
      


      if(classList.contains('deleteUser')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        userid = targetElement.dataset.userid;
        fname = targetElement.dataset.fname;
        lname = targetElement.dataset.lname;
        fullname = fname + ' ' + lname;

        if (window.confirm('Are You Sure To Delete '+ fullname +'?')) {
          $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              user_id: userid,
              f_name: fname,
              l_name: lname
            },
            url: 'database/delete-user.php', 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
              if(data.success) {
                if(window.confirm(data.message)){
                  location.reload();
                }
              }else window.alert(data.message);
              
            }
          })
        } else {
            console.log('will not delete');
        }
      }
    if(classList.contains('updateUser')){
            e.preventDefault();
            userId = targetElement.dataset.userid;
           firstName = targetElement.closest('tr').querySelector('td.firstName').innerHTML;
           lastName = targetElement.closest('tr').querySelector('td.lastName').innerHTML;
           userName = targetElement.closest('tr').querySelector('td.email').innerHTML;
           

      }
  });
  }
}
var script = new script;
script.initialize();
    </script>
```

when i lunch my script in chrome extension, every thing is working normally as i coded, except the <a> of "updateUser", what i fugered out that i trying to get before getting DOM that reads the innerHTML, but i don't know how to solve it, and i got this error in my  network:

```js
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        function script(){
  this.initialize = function(){
    this.registerEvents();
  };

  this.registerEvents = function(){
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      targetElement = e.target;
      classList = targetElement.classList;
      


      if(classList.contains('deleteUser')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        userid = targetElement.dataset.userid;
        fname = targetElement.dataset.fname;
        lname = targetElement.dataset.lname;
        fullname = fname + ' ' + lname;

        if (window.confirm('Are You Sure To Delete '+ fullname +'?')) {
          $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              user_id: userid,
              f_name: fname,
              l_name: lname
            },
            url: 'database/delete-user.php', 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
              if(data.success) {
                if(window.confirm(data.message)){
                  location.reload();
                }
              }else window.alert(data.message);
              
            }
          })
        } else {
            console.log('will not delete');
        }
      }
    if(classList.contains('updateUser')){
            e.preventDefault();
            userId = targetElement.dataset.userid;
           firstName = targetElement.closest('tr').querySelector('td.firstName').innerHTML;
           lastName = targetElement.closest('tr').querySelector('td.lastName').innerHTML;
           userName = targetElement.closest('tr').querySelector('td.email').innerHTML;
           

      }
  });
  }
}
var script = new script;
script.initialize();
    </script>
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:border-box}body,h1,h2,h3,h4,p,figure,blockquote,dl,dd{margin:0}ul[role="list"],ol[role="list"]{list-style:none}html:focus-within{scroll-behavior:smooth}body{min-height:100vh;text-rendering:optimizeSpeed;line-height:1.5}a:not([class]){text-decoration-skip-ink:auto}img,picture{max-width:100%;display:block}input,button,textarea,select{font:inherit}@media(prefers-reduced-motion:reduce){html:focus-within{scroll-behavior:auto}*,*::before,*::after{animation-duration:.01ms !important;animation-iteration-count:1 !important;transition-duration:.01ms !important;scroll-behavior:auto !important}}

body#loginBody{
background: url('../images/login-background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
}
body{
    font-family: arial;
}

div.loginHeader{
    text-align: center;
    
}
div.loginHeader{
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}
div.loginHeader h1{
    font-size: 100px;
    color: darkviolet;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.loginHeader p{
    color: aqua;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.loginHeader p:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: aqua;   
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div.loginBody form{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
    padding: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
div.loginInputsContainer{
margin-top:20px;
}

div.loginInputsContainer label{
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;

}
div.loginInputsContainer input{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid aqua;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}
div.loginButtonContainer{
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.loginButtonContainer button{
font-size:20px;
padding: 10px 40px;
background: aqua;
border: none;
color: yellow;
}
/*bodystyling*/
div.header{
    width:100%;
    background: aqua;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
div.header a{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
div.header a:hover{
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
div.banner{
background: url('../images/banner.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
padding-top: 100px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
height: 80vh;
}
div.homepagecontainer{
    width:100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.bannerheader h1{
   font-size: 100px;
   color: aqua;
   line-height: 100%;
}
div.bannerheader p{
   font-size: 40px;
   color: aqua;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   line-height: 100%;
}
p.bannertagline {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:#fff;
}
div.bannericons{
    margin-top: 150px;
}
div.bannericons a{
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #868485;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.bannericons a:first-child{
margin-left: 0px;
}
div.bannericons a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    background: aqua;
    transition: .5s all;

}
/*icons styling*/
div.homepagefeatures{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 50px 0px;
}
div.homepagefeature{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.33%;
}
div.homepagefeature:hover{
    border-top: 2px solid aqua;
    border-bottom: 2px solid aqua;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}
div.homepagefeature span.featureicon{
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 50px;
        background: #f685a1;
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: 5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.homepagefeature h3.featuretitle{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 23px;

}
div.homepagefeature p.featurediscription{
    color: 848484;
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
div.hoempagenotified{
        background: #e3e3e3;
        padding: 80px 0px;
}
div.homepagenotifiescontainer{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
}
div.emailform h3{
    font-size: 25px;
}
div.emailform{
    width: 40%;
}
div.video{
    width: 60% ;
    text-align: center;
}
div.hoempagenotified h3{
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
}
div.hoempagenotified p{
    color: #848484;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
div.formcontainer{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;

}
div.formcontainer input{
     width: 100%;
     padding: 15px 10px;
     border-radius: 15px;
     border: none;
}
div.formcontainer input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
div.formcontainer button{
 position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     font-size: 22px;
     padding: 0px 10px;
     background: aqua;
     border: none;
     color: #fff;
     border-top-right-radius: 15px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;

}
.vedio{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    /*the footer*/
}
div.socials{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0 40px 0px;
}
h3.socialheader{
    font-size: 30px;
}
p.socialtext{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #848484;
    font-size: 20px;
}
div.socialiconscontainer a{
    font-size: 23px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-top: 7px ;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
div.socialiconscontainer a:hover{
    background: aqua;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}
div.footer{
    background: #e3e3e3;
    padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        text-align: center; 
}
div.footer a{
    color: #848484;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.footer a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: aqua;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    

}
/*DASHBOARD STYLE*/
#dashboardmaincontainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
div.dashboard_sidebar{
        width:20%;
        background: black;
        height: 100vh;

}
div.dashboard_content_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #FFE808;

}
h3.dashboard_logo{
    color: darkviolet;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.dashboard_sidebar_user{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
div.dashboard_sidebar_user img{
    width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #323232;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.dashboard_sidebar_user span{
    top: 20%;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: darkviolet;
 display: inline-block;
 
}
ul.dashboard_menu_lists{
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
ul.dashboard_menu_lists li{
    padding: 15px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.dashboard_menu_lists li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkviolet;
    font-size: 30px;
}
ul.dashboard_menu_lists li a i{
    font-size: 30px;
}
ul.dashboard_menu_lists li.menuActive{
    display: block;
    background: #EFE904;
}
ul.dashboard_menu_lists li:hover{
    background: #FFE808;
    transition: 0.50s all;
}
div.dashboard_topNav{
    background: gold;
    padding: 20px;
}
div.dashboard_topNav a{
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a#logoutBtn{
float: right;
}
div.dashboard_content{
    padding: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
    
}
div.dashboard_content_main{
    background: #cecfd7;
    min-height: 650px;
    height: 100%;
        
}
div#Errormessage{
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 11px;
}
form::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
form.appform{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 6px solid #FFE808;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: darkviolet;
}
form label{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-weight: 800%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
form input.appforminput{
    width: 100%;
    height: 33px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
div.appforminputcontainer{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div#useraddformcontainer{
    padding-top: 100px;
}

button.appbtn{
 background: #ffd700;
 border: 2px solid darkred; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-style: oblique;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 float: right;
}
p.responsemessage{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 33px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
}
p.responsemessage__error{
    background: red;

}
p.responsemessage__success{
    background: #ffd700;
}
/* User Add Page */
div.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
div.column{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
div.column-5{
    width: 41.67%;
}
div.column-7{
    width: 58.33%;
}
h1.sectionheader{
    font-size: 21px;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ffd700;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 8px solid #ffd700;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table,th, td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 15px;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
}
table th{
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f4f6f9 ;

}
table td{
    font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
   padding: 5px;
}
p.usercount{
    text-align: right;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: black;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header('location: login.php');
$_SESSION['table'] = 'users';
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$users = include('database/show-users.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dashboard - Assure ERP System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css?v=<? time(); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dashboardmaincontainer">
        <?php include('partials/app-sidebar.php')?>
<div class="dashboard_content_container" id="dashboard_content_container">
    <?php include('partials/app-topnav.php')?>
    <div id="dashboard_content">
    <div class="dashboard_content_main">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-5">
        <h1 class="sectionheader"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Insert User</h1>
      <div id="useraddformcontainer">
      <form action="database/user-add.php" method="POST" class="appform">
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="first_name">first name</label>
          <input type="text" class="appforminput" id="first_name" name="first_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="last_name">last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="appforminput" id="last_name" name="last_name" />
        </div>
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="appforminput" id="email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="appforminputcontainer">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="appforminput" id="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="appbtn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>add user</button>
      </form>
       <?php if(isset($_SESSION['response'])) {
              $response_message = $_SESSION['response']['message'];
              $is_success = $_SESSION['response']['success'];
              ?>
              <div class="responsemessage">
                <p class="responsemessage <?= $is_success ? 'responsemessage__success' : 'responsemessage__error'?>">
                  <?= $response_message ?>
                </p>
              </div>
            <?php unset($_SESSION['response']); }?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column column-7">
        
        <h1 class="sectionheader"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> List of Users</h1>
        <div class="section_content">
          <div class="users">
         <table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>#</td>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Created At</th>
<th>Updated At</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($users as $index => $user){?>
    
    

    <tr>
    <td><?= $index + 1?></td>
  <td class="firstName"><?= $user['first_name']?></td>
  <td class="lastName"><?= $user['last_name']?></td>
  <td class="userName"><?= $user['username']?></td>
  <td><?= date('M d, Y @ h:i:s A', strtotime($user['created_at'])) ?></td>
  <td><?= date('M d, Y @ h:i:s A', strtotime($user['updated_at'])) ?></td>
  <td>
    <a href="" class="updateUser" data-userid="<?= $user['id'] ?>" > <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
      <a href="" class="deleteUser" data-userid="<?= $user['id'] ?>" data-fname="<?= $user['first_name'] ?>" data-lname="<?= $user['last_name'] ?>" > <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
        </td>
</tr>  
  <?php }?>

</tbody>
</table>
  <p class="usercount"><?= count($users)?> Users</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The error could be because your querySelector() is not matching anything in the DOM.  I'm not familiar with debugging chrome extensions, but you probably would want to put a breakpoint on the line of script that is failing and check the values of the variables near there.

Comment: Don't use the Java tag for JavaScript questions. Those are different languages.